# I have confusion adding/linking HTML multiple pages to my Django website

Tags: python, html, django

I am new to Django web development. I have successfully created an index.html page and it viewed on 127.0.0.1:8000 successfully. But the problem now is I have to link multiple pages, for example an about and contact section. I created about.html and contact.html pages in the same directory where my index.html page is. But when i click on about or contact page, it is not showing. How can I link these pages to my website?

Comment: It's always easier for people to understand & help you better if you paste in your own tried sample code  alongside your question.

Answer (score 0):

Django is working on principle of MVT (Model, View, Template). From question you asked, you created just template part for other pages (just .html files in filestructure). You also need to create methods for these pages inside views.py of given app and possibly, also records for these pages inside urls.py.

It is highly recommended, to start with Django tutorial. Your question is detaily answered in [third part of it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial03/).